# jQuery. Check if the option element has selected attribute

Tags: jquery, html-select, html

I have a function that needs to be fired on window load only if there on page is no option elements that has "selected" attribute.

```
<option value="1" selected="selected">Option</option>
```

I tried to do this with no luck with next function:

```
function fireWhenLoad () 
{
if ( $('select option').is(':selected')) {
        alert("Selected");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Not Selected");
        runIfNoSelectedOptions();
    }
};

$(window).load(function(){
    fireWhenLoad();
});
```

The function alerts "Selected" in every case if options has "selected" attribute and if they don't.

So what am I doing wrong and how can I check if option element has "selected" attribute?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, Use $(document).ready() to enure dom elements have been loaded and then loop through the options. You are currently only selecting first option.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select option").each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.attr("selected") !== undefined) {
        alert("Selected");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Not Selected");
        runIfNoSelectedOptions();
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$.(document).ready()` functionality of JQuery to trigger your event.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

```
$('option').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':selected')){
       alert("Selected");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Not Selected");
        runIfNoSelectedOptions();
    }
});
```